# modmail system discord.py no response to reaction

Tags: python, discord.py

so i was making a discord bot and made a modmail system and got this error. can someone plz help and tell me where i am going wrong i searched many similar errors but didnt find the answer.
bot:

```
import random
import os
import sys
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)
client.remove_command("help")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('Do -help'))
    print('functioning...')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined the server.')
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(f'Hi {member.mention}, welcome to my Discord server!')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left the server.')

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

@client.command(brief="Load", help="Loading cogs")
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command(brief="Unload", help="Unloading cogs")
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')

@client.command(brief="Ping", help="The time it takes for a small data set to be transmitted from your device to a server on the Internet and back to your device again.")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency*1000)}ms')

@client.command(aliases=['test','8ball', 'future'], brief="8ball", help="A little fun game.")
async def _8ball(ctx, *,question):
    responses=[ "It is certain.",
                "It is decidedly so.",
                "Without a doubt.",
                "Yes definitely.",
                "You may rely on it.",
                "As I see it, yes.",
                "Most likely.",
                "Outlook good.",
                "Yes.",
                "Signs point to yes.",
                "Reply hazy, try again.",
                "Ask again later.",
                "Better not tell you now.",
                "Cannot predict now.",
                "Concentrate and ask again.",
                "Don't count on it.",
                "My reply is no.",
                "My sources say no.",
                "Outlook not so good.",
                "Very doubtful."]
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')

@client.command(aliases=['purge','clean'], brief="Purge", help="Clears a fixed number of messahes.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@client.command(brief="Kick", help="Kicks a person out of the guild.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def kick(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    message = f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name}, reason: {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Kicked {member.mention}')

@client.command(brief="Ban", help="Bans a person in the guild.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def ban(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name}, reason: {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Banned {member.mention}')

@client.command(brief="Unban", help="Unbans a banned person in the guild.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, user=None):
    try:
        user = await commands.converter.UserConverter().convert(ctx, user)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Error: user could not be found!")
        return
    try:
        bans = tuple(ban_entry.user for ban_entry in await ctx.guild.bans())
        if user in bans:
            await ctx.guild.unban(user, reason="Responsible moderator: "+ str(ctx.author))
        else:
            await ctx.send("User not banned!")
            return
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send("I do not have permission to unban!")
        return
    except:
        await ctx.send("Unbanning failed!")
        return
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully unbanned {user.mention}!")

class DurationConverter(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
        amount=argument[:-1]
        unit=argument[-1]
        if amount.isdigit() and unit in ['s','m','h','d']:
            return(int(amount),unit)
        raise commands.BadArgument(message="Not a valid duration")

@client.command(brief="Tempban", help="Temporarily bans a person in the guild.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def tempban(ctx, member: commands.MemberConverter, duration: DurationConverter):
    multiplier={'s':1, 'm':60, 'h':3600, 'd':86400}
    amount, unit= duration
    message = f"You have been banned from {ctx.guild.name}, for {amount}{unit}"
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.guild.ban(member)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} has been banned for {amount}{unit}')
    await asyncio.sleep(amount*multiplier[unit])
    await ctx.guild.unban(member)

@client.command(brief="Tempmute", help="Temporarily mutes a person in the guild.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, duration: DurationConverter, reason=None):
    multiplier = {'s': 1, 'm': 60, 'h': 3600, 'd': 86400}
    amount, unit = duration
    guild = ctx.guild
    muteRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.add_roles(muteRole, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been muted in {ctx.guild} for {amount}{unit}")
    await member.send(f"You have been muted in {ctx.guild} for {amount}{unit}")
    await asyncio.sleep(amount*multiplier[unit])
    await member.remove_roles(muteRole, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been unmuted in {ctx.guild} ")
    await member.send(f"You have been unmuted in {ctx.guild} ")

def restart_bot():
  os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

@client.command(name= 'restart', brief="Restart", help="Restarts the bot.")
async def restart(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Restarting bot...")
  restart_bot()

@client.command( brief="Connects", help="Connects the bot.")
async def connect(self):
    print(" bot connected")

@client.command(brief="Disconnects", help="Disconnects the bot.")
async def disconnect(self):
    print("bot disconnected")

@client.command(brief="Mute", help="Mutes a person in the guild.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    muteRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not muteRole:
        await ctx.send("No Mute Role found! Creating one now...")
        muteRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(muteRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_messages=True,
                                          read_message_history=True)
    await member.add_roles(muteRole, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been muted in {ctx.guild} | Reason: {reason}")
    await member.send(f"You have been muted in {ctx.guild} | Reason: {reason}")

@client.command(brief="Unmute", help="Unmutes a muted person in the guild.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    muteRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.remove_roles(muteRole, reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} has been unmuted in {ctx.guild}")
    await member.send(f"You have been unmuted in {ctx.guild}")

@client.command(brief="Slowmode", help="Enables a rate limit per message.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def slowmode(ctx, time:int):
    if (not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages):
        await ctx.send('Cannot run command! Requires: ``Manage Messages``')
        return
    if time == 0:
        await ctx.send('Slowmode is currently set to `0`')
        await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay = 0)
    elif time > 21600:
        await ctx.send('You cannot keep the slowmode higher than 6 hours!')
        return
    else:
        await ctx.channel.edit(slowmode_delay = time)
        await ctx.send(f"Slowmode has been set to `{time}` seconds!")

@client.command(brief="Prefix", help="Changes the prefix.")
async def setprefix(ctx, prefix):
    client.command_prefix = prefix
    await ctx.send(f"Prefix changed to ``{prefix}``")


@client.command(brief="Avatar", help="Displays a guild members pfp.")
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author
    icon_url = member.avatar_url
    avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}\'s Avatar", color=0x802BAE)
    avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f"{icon_url}")
    avatarEmbed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
    await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)

client.run(token)
```

modmail:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
client = discord.Client()
sent_users = []
class modmail(Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self,message):
        if message.guild:  # ensure the channel is a DM
            return

        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.author.id in sent_users:  # Ensure the intial message hasn't been sent before
            return

        modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="modmail")

        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00FFFF)
        embed.set_author(name=f"Modmail System",
                         icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/690937143522099220/34fbd058360c3d4696848592ff1c5191.webp?size=1024")
        embed.add_field(name='Report a member:', value=f"React with 1️⃣ if you want to report a member.")
        embed.add_field(name='Report a Staff Member:', value=f"React with 2️⃣ if you want to report a Staff Member.")
        embed.add_field(name='Warn Appeal:', value=f"React with 3️⃣ if you would like to appeal a warning.")
        embed.add_field(name='Question:',
                        value=f"React with 4️⃣ if you have a question about our moderation system or the server rules.")
        embed.set_footer(text="Modmail")
        msg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("1️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("3️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("4️⃣")

        sent_users.append(message.author.id)  # add this user to the list of sent users

        try:
            def check(reaction, user):
                 return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣"]

            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00FFFF)
                embed.set_author(name=f"Modmail System",
                                 icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/690937143522099220/34fbd058360c3d4696848592ff1c5191.webp?size=1024")
                embed.add_field(name='How to Report:',
                                value="Send the ID of the person you are reporting and attach add a screen shot of them breaking a rule (can be ToS or a server rule).")
                embed.set_footer(text="Report a member ")
                await message.author.send(embed=embed)

                message = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=60, check=lambda
                    m: m.channel == message.channel and m.author == message.author)
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message.content}", color=0x00FFFF)
                await modmail_channel.send(embed=embed)

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send("Reaction timeout!!!")

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
            print("modmail ready")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(modmail(bot))
```

logcog:

```
import discord
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext.commands import Cog

class Example(Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("log ready")

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.guild:
            pass
        else:
         if not message.content and message.channel:
            pass
         else:
            channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name='log')
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message sent", description=message.author, color=message.author.color,
                                  timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
            embed.add_field(name="Message Sent", value=message.content, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Channel Sent", value=message.channel, inline=True)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
        if len(before.content)==0 and len(after.content)==0 and len(before.channel)==0:
            pass
        elif not before.guild:
            pass
        else:
            channel = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name='log')
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message edited", description=before.author, color=before.author.color,
                                  timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
            embed.add_field(name="Before edit", value=before.content, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="After edit", value=after.content, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="Channel Sent", value=before.channel, inline=True)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, message):
        if not message.content and message.channel:
            pass
        elif not message.guild:
            pass
        else:
            channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name='log')
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message deleted", description=message.author, color=message.author.color,
                                  timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
            embed.add_field(name="Deleted Message", value=message.content, inline=True)
            embed.add_field(name="The channel is", value=message.channel, inline=True)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Example(client))
```

so when i run this code i get the reaction message and embed in the dm but when i click on the reaction i get no further out put and after 60s a message comes reaction timeout. I dont get any error message either.

[image: image of the problem]

Comment: I can't really test this right now but I suspect that `str(reaction.emoji) in ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣"]` is probably the line that is failing. It might be a good idea to compare the emoji IDs instead because strings can have different representations that look the same, which I think is what is happening here.

Comment: how do i get the emoji id and also how do i use it in the that line.

Comment: Actually I was completely wrong, after testing your code I've found that the `client.wait_for` command itself is not working as it doesn't seem to be receiving the event when it should. I will keep trying but as of now I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Comment: ok thx a lot again for your help. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved the problem, which stemmed from the intents setup. In my main file I used this code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
bot.load_extension("cogs.maincog")
bot.run(token)
```

You may want to do this slightly differently (like by using client), but the important part is the intents. This is apparently because the privileged intent "members" is required when testing for reactions is direct messages. I replaced the client with the Bot class, so the testing function became:

```
reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)
```

As far as I have tested, this should work perfectly well but let me know if you have any problems or want me to link the full code.

Edit: Look at how to enable privileged intents [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html).

Comment: so i have a bot.py file which is the main.py  in that i already have
```for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
````

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)

Comment: i tired even by changing client=discord.client statement to define client all over again in the cog still no diff i am not  getting any response.

Comment: Have you definitely enabled the members privileged intent in the discord developer portal because without that this will not work.

Comment: yes i did it i enabled for all members presences and messages.

Comment: should i send my cogs as well as main file code?

Comment: yes that sounds ideal

Comment: i sent the main.py as well as another cog which may be affecting. although i think error is prolly only in the main py or modmail cog. i have a few other cogs as well such as info cog help cog and error cog if it is needed u can post a comment.

Comment: Ok so as it turns out the problem lies in line 4 of your modmail file: `client = discord.Client()`. You shouldn't be creating a new client here, you should be using the bot class that is passed into the class, namely `self.bot`. This is because it is trying to wait for an event from a client which isn't actually connected to anything. If you remove this line and replace all the times you used client with `self.bot` it works perfectly.

Comment: Nice. Thank you it worked as you said when i changed client to self.bot